# Message (toast) not showing

Tags: java, android

I have a list of buttons and what I want to do is display some information on press. Here´s the code:

```
public class ActividadDos extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Map<CharSequence, String> info = new HashMap();

    private Button btnYogur;
    private Button btnChocolate;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividad_dos);

        btnYogur = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnYogur);
        btnChocolate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChocolate);

        info.put(btnYogur.getText(), "Lácteos");
        info.put(btnChocolate.getText(), "Grasas, aceites y dulces");
    }

    public void displayMensaje(View v) {
        Button button = (Button) v;
        String nombre = (String) button.getText();

        String mensaje = "Clasificación: " + info.get(nombre);

        Toast.makeText(ActividadDos.this, mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

It doesn´t show any errors but when I press the buttons it doesn´t display the message.
Similar code is working on another activity.

Comment: Where are you calling: `displayMensaje()`?

Comment: Isn't displaying anything because you aren't calling `displayMensaje` method at all, right? Please responde with @.

Comment: Did you add android:onClick="displayMensaje" to the button at activity_actividad_dos.xml

Comment: @AlexMamo you're right. I added that call and it´s functioning perfectly.

Comment: @DexterNaru Good to hear that. I just posted an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call displayMensaje() method.

Add this to .xml for corresponding button(As per requirement)

android:onClick="displayMensaje"

Answer (score 0):

It isn't displaying anything because you aren't calling `displayMensaje()` method anywhere in your code at all. To solve this, please add a call to this method and your problem will be solved.